# Запрос из таблицы с внешним ключом

Tags: postgresql, select

У меня есть две таблицы в БД postgreSQL - users и reports.

> users

- id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
- personal_id INTEGER NOT NULL
- name VARCHAR

> reports

- id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
- personal INTEGER NOT NULL
- work VARCHAR
- FOREIGN KEY (personal) REFERENCES users(personal_id)

Я пытаюсь понять как выгружать данные из таблицы "reports" по имени пользователя из таблицы "users". Сейчас я делаю вот так:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
INNER JOIN reports
ON reports.personal = users.personal_id
WHERE users.name = 'Test';
```

Так у меня получается выгрузить все отчеты пользователя "Test", но я получаю две таблицы в одной:

```
| id | personal_id | name | id | personal | work |
| 1  | 12345       | Test | 55 | 12345    | text |
```

Я хочу выгрузить все отчеты, но вместо столбца "personal", чтоб было соответствующее имя из таблицы "users" , подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать? Не могу понять.

Comment: а вы вместо `*` пишите явные поля. или `имя таблицы.*`

Comment: Спасибо больше, ломал голову думал какое-то общее решение есть, оказывается просто перечислить нужные столбцы из обоих таблиц. Еще раз спасибо, и прошу прощения за глупый вопрос.